# cannot access FTP server over the network

Tags: ftp

I created an IIS FTP server.

The local machine IP Address is xx.xx.xx.112.
I can connect locally by using xx.xx.xx.112 username and password

However when I on the same network on a different computer
xx.xx.xx.111 I cannot connect.

Comment: It sounds like an issue with a firewall.  Allow the traffic on the port and/or forward the traffic to the port to that specific device.  Making a connection to the device, while on the device, does not indicate if it will be accessible from another device on the intranet and/or internet

Comment: Please review your firewall rules. If you have a software firewall running (including Windows Firewall), mention what firewall is in use, and share any applicable rules you have created that should allow FTP. Also be aware if there may be any sort of hardware firewalling on the network (e.g. managed switches that might not permit FTP traffic).